# Python - Expanding and Simplifying a program

Tags: python, function

I have a program which calculates the perfect squares up to a user input upper bound. My code is :

```
"""Print all the perfect squares from zero up to a given maximum."""
import math

def read_bound():
   """Reads the upper bound from the standard input (keyboard).
      If the user enters something that is not a positive integer
      the function issues an error message and retries
      repeatedly"""
   upper_bound = None
   while upper_bound is None:
       line = input("Enter the upper bound: ")
       if line.isnumeric() and int(line) >= 0:
           upper_bound = int(line)
           return upper_bound
       else:
           print("You must enter a positive number.")



def is_perfect_square(num):
   """Return true if and only if num is a perfect square"""
   root = math.sqrt(num)
   return int(root) - root == 0



def print_squares(upper_bound, squares):
   """Print a given list of all the squares up to a given upper bound"""


   print("The perfect squares up to {} are: ". format(upper_bound))
   for square in squares:
       print(square, end=' ')



def main():
   """Calling the functions"""
   upper_bound = read_bound()
   squares = []
   for num in range(2, upper_bound + 1):
       if is_perfect_square(num):
           squares.append(num)

   print_squares(upper_bound, squares)


main()
```

I would like to expand this program slightly to also include a lower bound so the program calculates and prints perfect squares between the two bounds `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`. While doing this, I want to also generalise the `read_bound()` function so that it works for both the lower and upper bounds while still printing a prompt suitable prompt string as the original program does. I have come up with a pathway to a possible solution through passing the required prompt strings to the `read_bound()` function so that the main function becomes something like:

```
def main():
   """Every home should have one"""
   lower_bound = read_bound("Enter the lower bound: ")
   upper_bound = read_bound("Enter the upper bound: ")
   squares = []
   for num in range(lower_bound, upper_bound + 1):
       if is_perfect_square(num):
           squares.append(num)

   print_squares(lower_bound, upper_bound, squares)
```

Is this a valid pathway to a solution to adding a lower bound to my program while also generalizing it? If so how can I adjust my `read_bound()` and `print_squares` functions to accommodate for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could change your code to something like this:

```
"""
Print all the perfect squares from zero up to a given maximum.
"""

import math

def read_bound(msg):
    """
    Reads a bound from the standard input (keyboard).  If the user
    enters something that is not a positive integer the function issues an
    error message and retries repeatedly
    """
    upper_bound = None
    while upper_bound is None:
         line = input(msg)
         if line.isnumeric() and int(line) >= 0:
              upper_bound = int(line)
              return upper_bound
         else:
              print("You must enter a positive number.")

def is_perfect_square(num):
    """
    Return true if and only if num is a perfect square
    """
    root = math.sqrt(num)
    return int(root) - root == 0

def print_squares(lower_bound, upper_bound, squares):
    """
    Print a given list of all the squares up to a given upper bound
    """
    print("The perfect squares between {} and {} are: ". format(lower_bound, upper_bound))
    for square in squares:
         print(square, end=' ')
    print()

def calculate_squares(lower_bound, upper_bound):
    return filter(is_perfect_square, range(lower_bound, upper_bound))

def main():
    """
    Calling the functions
    """
    lower_bound = read_bound("Enter the lower bound: ")
    upper_bound = read_bound("Enter the upper bound: ")
    print_squares(lower_bound, upper_bound,
                  calculate_squares(lower_bound, upper_bound + 1))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've separated the logic for calculating squares into another function, `calculate_squares`. NB this function behaves lazily, so not all squares are stored - this is generally desirable. `print_squares` then consumes them one by one, so for a very large range, you might see some live buffered printing. The other change is that it now uses `range(lower_bound, upper_bound)`. It assumes `upper_bound` is non-inclusive, so in the main function it's called with `upper_bound + 1`. It uses `filter` to "filter" the range for perfect squares.

`read_bound` now also takes an `msg` argument, which seems to do what you want. The code executes like this:

```
Enter the lower bound: 20
Enter the upper bound: 100
The perfect squares between 20 and 100 are: 1
25 36 49 64 81 100
```

You should be wary that this code doesn't behave how you might think for very large integers, eg:

```
>>> is_perfect_square((1 << 500) + 1)
True
>>> is_perfect_square(1 << 500)
True
```

This means that something like this might happen:

```
Enter the lower bound: 3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589377
Enter the upper bound: 3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589387
The perfect squares between 3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589377 and 3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589387 are: 
3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589377 3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589378 3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589379 3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589380 3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589381 3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589382 3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589383 3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589384 3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589385 3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589386 3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589387
```

Here your program has determined that every integer between the two given integers is a square.

This is due to Python's arbitrary size integers but finite size floats. There is a rounding error in `math.sqrt` here, as Python can't actually represent it any other way. To account for this will be tricky - I'd recommend that rather than working backwards from potential squares, you work forwards from integer roots to squares, although this is nontrivial - a reliable way to jump to the lower bound without rounding errors could well be very complicated to implement.